# My MacBook Pro screen glitches when watching videos on safari

Tags: macbook-pro

It only seems to happen when watching videos on safari, I tried on Firefox and it doesn't, at least not yet. What could that be ? I had my logic board replaced twice already and now I just got past the 90 days period so if it has an issue again...

My Mac is up to date using Big Sur

Any idea ?
[image]

Comment: A little more detail would help, such as the model of your MBP and what your video source is, e.g. streamed over internet, .mpg, .wmv, .mp4, etc. If this is happening in Safari, but not Firefox, then it's likely the difference on codecs in the browsers.

Comment: Can you leave Activity Monitor running in the background and keep an eye out for what your memory pressure and CPU usage look like during these events?

Comment: My Mac is a late 2019 16 inch MacBook Pro, 16 gigs of ram.
That's a 1080p YouTube video, also restarting the Mac didn't solve the issue.